# Toggle CCK field visibility with CCK radio buttons

Tags: nodes, entities, 6

I have a content type with three cck fields

1 radio button, 1 text field, and 1 integer field.

What I am trying to do is by default have the text field and integer field hidden, and only show them dependent on the state of the radio button.

Example:

Two radio buttons, one which says *text* and one which says *integer*.  When the *text* radio box is checked, then the text box shows and the integer box is hidden and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

There is a contrib module written for just this: [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the [States API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7).
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.

Comment: it work for me :) thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use client-side javascript for this. For example, the jQuery show/hide functions can be used to expose your text and integer fields depending on the value of the radio button.

Comment: any example site

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy doing a very small amount of coding, then this can be achieved in a way that is far more lightweight than using the conditional fields module.

In a custom module you can implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and use the [states api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) to add the visibility rules.  You don't actually need to program the logic for hiding / displaying the fields, just define which values to use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_form_CONTENTTYPENAME_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['text_field']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="radio_field"]' => array('value' => 'value_of_textfield_option'),
    ),
  );    

  $form['integar_field']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="radio_field"]' => array('value' => 'value_of_integarfield_option'),
    ),
  );
}
```